# add column dynamically to table json and angular.js

Tags: json, angularjs

I want to add a column dynamically to the table. My code is based on angularjs and json. The table structure is defined in a file abc.json. I want to a column to this table. I ant to do it dynamically.

I tried the following:

```
var newCol = [{name: "abc", type: "textarea", displayName: "ABC"}];
table.push(newCol);
$scope.cfg = table;
table = angular.copy($scope.cfg);
```

I am able to add new column but the column data is always undefined. Moreover, I want this column to be stored in the table once it is added.

Comment: Please detail what have you done so far. Show some implementation details.

Comment: @EpokK, I tried your suggestion. It seems that the column is added but I am not able to get see the data. The data is always "undefined".

Answer (score 4):

Check this:

(in your controller)

```
--- JAVASCRIPT ---
$scope.table = ['1', '2', '3']; // abc.json
$scope.table.push('4'); // add column
```

(your structure)

```
--- HTML ---
<table>
   <tr ng-repeat="column in table">
      <td>
         <span ng-bind="column"></span>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```